# how to paste a rotate image without cropping sides

Tags: python, image

[this is the original back image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmmwB.jpg)
[this is the original front image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w1xs.jpg)
this is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
front=Image.open('/users/apple/Desktop/TMP.jpeg')
back=Image.open('/Users/apple/Desktop/原始图片/084.jpeg')
front=front.rotate(100,expand=True)
back.paste(front,(100,100))
back
```

[this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WynCv.jpg).
i want a clean paste without cropping sides.
can somebody help me ,thanks.

Comment: If you want to rotate an image without border or cropping you have to do it in 90 degree steps, since computer images are rectangular.

Answer (score 8):

You need to generate a mask that you can pass to `paste` to exclude the new black edges.

```
mask = Image.new('L', front.size, 255)
front = front.rotate(100, expand=True)
mask = mask.rotate(100, expand=True)
back.paste(front, (100,100), mask)
```

[image: Result]